# Lie algebra basis and generators

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

In [Supergravity by Freedman](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=7ANrOHJLTjMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (specifically sections 1.2.1 & 1.2.3), he states that given an element $R$ of the group $SO(n)$, the infinitesimal form of $R$ is given by,

\begin{equation}
R^i_j = \delta^i_j - \epsilon r^i_j \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

The Lie algebra is the linear space spanned by the $\frac{1}{2}n(n − 1)$ independent generators, with the commutator,

\begin{equation}
[r,r'] = r r' - r' r \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}

A useful basis for the Lie algebra is to choose generators that act in each of the $\frac{1}{2}n(n − 1)$ independent 2-planes of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the 2-plane in the directions $\hat{i}\hat{j}$ this generator is given by,

\begin{equation}
r_{[\hat{i}\hat{j}]}\;^i_j = \delta^i_{\hat{i}} \delta_{\hat{j}j} - \delta^i_{\hat{j}} \delta_{\hat{i}j} \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}

In this basis, a finite transformation of $SO(n)$ is determined by a set of $\frac{1}{2}n(n − 1)$ real parameters $θ^{\hat{i}\hat{j}}$ which specify the angles of rotation in the independent 2-planes. A finite rotation can be written as,

\begin{equation}
R = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \theta^{\hat{i}\hat{j}} r_{[\hat{i}\hat{j}]}} \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}

This concept is of course also applied to the Lorentz group, so that for the 2-plane in the directions $\rho\sigma$, the Lorentz generator $m_{\mu\nu}$ is given by,

\begin{equation}
m_{[\rho\sigma]}\;^\mu_{\;\nu} = \delta^\mu_\rho \eta_{\nu\sigma} - \delta^\mu_\sigma \eta_{\rho\nu} \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation}

The finite transformation is given by,

\begin{equation}
\Lambda = e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda^{\rho\sigma} m_{[\rho\sigma]}} \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation}

where $\lambda^{\rho\sigma} = -\lambda^{\sigma\rho}$.

This is the first time I encountered this concept, I'm familiar with the usual rotation generator $r$ and the parameter $\theta$ so that $R=e^{-\frac{1}{2} \theta^k r_k}$ where the index $k$ denotes which direction the rotation is done, e.g. $r_3$ generates the rotation in the $z$-direction with rotation angle $\theta^3 = \theta_0$.

Questions:

(1) Can anyone explain properly the concept of this basis and how (to write) those extra indices come up?

(2) How to derive $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{5}$?

(3) Why does $\lambda^{\rho\sigma} = -\lambda^{\sigma\rho}$?